# Magento 2 REST API - Encrypted Authentication

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I would know if it is possible to use the REST API of Magento using a Basic Auth approch.

The idea of the token authentication, as described in the [doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html) is very simple and good for my purpose but for a security reason I couldn't send in the payload the information not encrypted (imagine that there is a subagent  in the communication that receives this payload and use it to authenticate the user )

So, there is a method to make the authentication to the endpoint, but using Base64 BasicAuth?

For example :

```
Endpoint
POST http://<host>/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token

Headers
Content-Type application/json

Data:
{
"credentials": "BASE64(admin:123123q)",
}
```